# Decorating Properties

Tags: c#

I would like to "decorate" properties of my own objects. Say for instance, I would like to know how many times a getter was called, how long the setter takes, logging any new values...

I am trying to achieve this as simpliest as possible. An ideal solution may use attribute, it could look like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
    [CountGetterCalls]
    [LogSettingValue]
    public int SomeProperty;
}
```

I did not succeed in implementing this, as a solution, I tried a kind of property wrapper. But that is far from being perfect. What would be your approach ?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        SomeProperty = new PropertyWrapper<int>(new CountCallsPropertyDecorator<int>(new LogSettingPropertyDecorator<int>(new NullDecorator<int>())));
    }

    public PropertyWrapper<int> SomeProperty;
}

public interface IPropertyDecorator<T>
{
    void OnGetValue();
    void OnSetValue(T value);
}

public class PropertyWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly IPropertyDecorator<T> _decorator;
    private T _value;

    public PropertyWrapper(IPropertyDecorator<T> decorator)
    {
        _decorator = decorator;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            _decorator.OnGetValue();
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _decorator.OnSetValue(value);
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CountCallsPropertyDecorator<T> : IPropertyDecorator<T>
{
    private readonly IPropertyDecorator<T> _decorator;
    private int _nbGetCalled;
    private int _nbSetCalled;

    public int NbGetCalled { get { return _nbGetCalled; } }
    public int NbSetCalled { get { return _nbSetCalled; } }

    public CountCallsPropertyDecorator(IPropertyDecorator<T> decorator)
    {
        _decorator = decorator;
    }

    public void OnGetValue()
    {
        _decorator.OnGetValue();
        _nbGetCalled++;
    }

    public void OnSetValue(T value)
    {
        _decorator.OnSetValue(value);
        _nbSetCalled++;
    }
}

public class LogSettingPropertyDecorator<T> : IPropertyDecorator<T>
{
    private readonly IPropertyDecorator<T> _decorator;

    public LogSettingPropertyDecorator(IPropertyDecorator<T> decorator)
    {
        _decorator = decorator;
    }

    public void OnGetValue() { _decorator.OnGetValue(); }
    public void OnSetValue(T value)
    {
        _decorator.OnSetValue(value);
        Console.WriteLine("Property called.");
    }
}

public class NullDecorator<T> : IPropertyDecorator<T>
{
    public void OnGetValue() { }

    public void OnSetValue(T value) { }
}
```

Comment: There is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: If this is working code it doesn't belong here because it is primarily opinion-based. For a review of your code, you can always post this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Or Castle's [DynamicProxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx).

Comment: Attributes cannot be used for that since they are only “attachments” to the objects they are added to. They are not decorators.

Comment: BTW, what's the purpose of this? If you are trying to profile your app, why not simply use a profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net, method "decoration" doesn't work as others languages (Python for example), the presence of an attribute doesn't change the behavior of the method, just its metadata. The metadata can be used to change its behavior by other tools.

You need and AOP framework (like the proprietary [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/)) or a dynamic proxy generator (like [LinFu](https://github.com/philiplaureano/LinFu) or [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/)) to achieve exactly what you want.

Both have his vantages and disadvantages, take a look on each.